# If a ($k$-Nearest-Neighbors) k NN algorithm performs very well for low k, can I infer something about the data set?

Tags: machine-learning, k-nearest-neighbour

I am running k NN on a very small data set for binary classification. Each class has 100 samples. I am getting the best performances for $k=1$ and $k=3$. Can I deduce information about my data set from k NN performing very well for small values of $k$?

Comment: The most immediate deduction is that something is going wrong. $k$ means has to get better (on average) as $k$ increases. So what does it mean when you say you are getting "best performance"? What is your measure of "best?"

Comment: My performance measure is the ratio of labels that are classified correctly over the total labels.

Comment: Either you have very low (or even zero) variance, or you are assessing performance incorrectly and actually overfitting.  Are you using all your data both for learning and testing or did you separate it in a learning sub-dataset and testing sub-dataset?

Comment: I am using kfold cross validation with k=10.